# Multiple SSH keys on CentOS

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, git

Scenario: I have a project using Bitbucket as a remote repo for Git. Local environment is a MacBook Pro, remote (production) environment is CentOS.

Generated a keypair on the MacBook Pro, placed the public key into Bitbucket, authenticates without any issues.

Generated another keypair on the MacBook pro, placed the public key onto the CentOS box (via CPanel, but confirmed that it's added to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys), and I can authenticate without any issues.

Generate another keypair on the CentOS box, placed the public key into Bitbucket. All git commands continue to default to password authentication instead of the keypair. Confirmed the public key is also in authorized_keys. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using an HTTPS URL or an SSH URL on the CentOS box?  Can you show us the exact commands you're running and the output you're seeing as a code block?

Comment: Sheesh, you're pinpointed the issue. I had cloned the repo using HTTPS on the CentOS box. Switching it to an SSH URL resolved the issue. Thanks!